# Weird characters in a std::vector<TCHAR*>

Tags: c++, winapi, tchar

Trying to get all sub directories, and eventually all files in sub directories, and I'm passing a std::vector as a reference to a function that actually gets all of the directories. I can cout the cFileName inside the function but once it returns the main the vector has weird characters.

Currently have my Character Set to use Unicode. When I was using multibyte it would actually print weird characters, now it prints nothing. The vector does have something in it (directories.size() returns a value > 0)

Can't really think of anything else. Hopefully this was a good question lol. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Declare function prototypes
DWORD listDirectories(std::vector<TCHAR*>&);

// Global variable that holds the current working path of the program
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];

void main()
{
    // Declare variables, dwCount for return value from listDirectories, directories stores all sub directories, cDirectory stores current directory
    DWORD dwCount;
    //std::vector<TCHAR*> directories;
    std::vector<TCHAR*> directories;
    TCHAR cDirectory[MAX_PATH];

    // Get current directory
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, buffer);

    // Set cDirectory (current directory) to buffer (ATM is current directory) + add \\ to the end and make it the working directory
    _tcscpy_s(cDirectory, buffer);
    _tcscat_s(cDirectory, L"\\*");

    // dwCount is count of how many directories found, to be used later
    dwCount = listDirectories(directories);

    // Range for loop to print each value in the std::vector<TCHAR*> directories
    for (auto tStr : directories) {
        // Doing wcout here prints weird characters.
        std::wcout << tStr << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
}   // end void main()

DWORD listDirectories(std::vector<TCHAR*> &directories)
{
    // Declare variables, count used for number of directories, hFind for FindFirstFile, data used to store file data
    DWORD count = 0;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    TCHAR currentDir[MAX_PATH];

    // Copy the current working directory into currentDir, will be used for subDir
    _tcscpy_s(currentDir, buffer);

    // Append "\\*" to buffer to make it a working directory
    _tcscat_s(buffer, L"\\*");

    // Find first file in the current working directory, storying data in data as a reference
    hFind = FindFirstFile(buffer, &data);

    // If hFind is not an invalid handle
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        // Go through each file in the directory
        do
        {
            // If the file attributes is a directory
            if (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                // Create a sub directory
                TCHAR subDir[MAX_PATH];

                // Fill subDir with current directory + "\\" + dir name
                _tcscpy_s(subDir, currentDir);
                _tcscat_s(subDir, L"\\");
                _tcscat_s(subDir, data.cFileName);

                // Fill subDir with current directory + "\\" + dir name
                //sprintf_s(subDir, "%s%s%s", currentDir, "\\", data.cFileName);

                // Add directory to my directories (std::vector<TCHAR*>) if count > 1, because I don't want the "." and ".." directories
                if (count > 1){
                    directories.push_back(subDir);
                    // Doing wcout here prints the subDir just fine and works properly
                    std::wcout << subDir << std::endl;
                }

                // Add 1 to count, used as the return for how many directories found in the current directory
                count++;
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data) != 0);
    }

    // Return count of directories found. -2 to get rid of the "." and ".." directories
    return (count - 2);
}   // end DWORD listDirectories(std::vector<TCHAR*>&)
```

Comment: Time to stop using TCHAR unless you still support Win98.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `listDirectories()` function

```
TCHAR subDir[MAX_PATH];
...
directories.push_back(subDir);
```

`subDir` is an array local to the `do ... while` loop within the function and its lifetime ends with every iteration of the loop.

Change `std::vector<TCHAR*> directories;` to `std::vector<std::basic_string<TCHAR>> directories;` and your code should work correctly. Now you'll make a copy of the directory name and add that to the `vector`.

---

Another alternative is to forget about all the `TCHAR` stuff and just use the wide character versions of everything when dealing with the Windows API.

```
std::vector<std::wstring> directories;
wchar_t cDirectory[MAX_PATH];
...
hFind = FindFirstFileW(buffer, &data);
```

and so forth

Comment: making it a std::basic_string worked flawlessly.
I don't know much, if anything, about windows coding. This was just my first attempt to get into it. TCHAR was just chosen because I knew it was a typdef for char* that supported multibyte and unicode.

I'm just gonna use wstring though since I know it's simpler and if it does work with the windows API.
Thank you.